# How to upgrade ASP Identity Membership from 2.2 to 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, authentication, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP Identity 2.2.x (2.x) targeting .NET 4.6/system.web.mvc 5.2.3 *which in reality seems like its MVC 5* (another confusing ball game for me).

Now that I saw **ASP Identity 3.0** [released here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity) and [here](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Roadmap), I was looking to upgrade, but don't know if its simple replace or more complicated -

1. Can I upgrade to 3.0 inside the current 4.6 target run time, or do I need DNX?
2. Is 4.6 considered ASP MVC 5 (yes, I am using System.Web.Mvc 5.2.3), so this should be compatible based on the the two links above, right?
3. What does Identity 3.x buy me thats not in 2.x
4. What does it involve, has anyone cared to venture :)

Comment: Similar question here and not properly answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36345121/how-to-migrate-database-schema-from-identity-2-2-0-to-3-0-0-rc1-final also not very clear here https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/identity.html