# How Can I generate Identity DB Scripts without migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, identityserver4

I've been trying to fix a project so it has the db script for IdentityServer4. I've been informed to run

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerMigration -c PersistedGrantDbContext
```

However when I run that I receive an error:

> dotnet: No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"

So I followed a few [resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet) for getting dotnet-ef

and I Installed a few nuget packagets:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

but still affter all that I receive the same error message.

Is there another way to get the script for a Identity4 DB?

Comment: look at this: http://identity.codeplex.com/

Comment: is the schema the same for Identity2 and Identity4?

Comment: unfortunately no, but its slightly different : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36345121/how-to-migrate-database-schema-from-identity-2-2-0-to-3-0-0-rc1-final

Comment: I think I'm screwed.  that only works for visual studio 2012-2013, I only have 2015 and 2017 both of which do no want to work for some reason

Comment: search a little bit i believe there are someone who wanted the same thing. i will search as well, will include here if i found something.

Comment: @Valkyriee thanks,  I've been working on this authentication problem for like 2 weeks it seems like every resource I find just leads me to another issue.  Ha, but I know eventually I will get it all working

Comment: Thats the issue with new technologies, surething u will find it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running the older style syntax in the Package Manager Console (which is using Powershell).

```
Add-Migration InitialIdentityServerPersistedGrantDbMigration -c PersistedGrantDbContext -o Data/Migrations/IdentityServer/PersistedGrantDb
Add-Migration InitialIdentityServerConfigurationDbMigration -c ConfigurationDbContext -o Data/Migrations/IdentityServer/ConfigurationDb
Update-Database -c PersistedGrantDbContext
Update-Database -c ConfigurationDbContext
```

Comment: glad to help :-)

Comment: yeah that was it.  This was plaguing me that's why I didn't post the identityServer4 instuctions in the other post yet.   Thanks I owe you.

Comment: do you know which migration I have to run to get the Application DB context,  I think it contains ASP.NetUsers table?

Comment: @travis.js I' having issues that the context is not found. How did you resolve that?

Comment: This helped 1 Vote Up

Answer (score 1):

Here are the .sql files on [GitHub repository](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/tree/dev/src/Host/Migrations/IdentityServer) to install the SQL tables.

Comment: In 2020 above link is broken, here is the [Github](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/src/EntityFramework.Storage/migrations/SqlServer/Migrations) latest link for SQL Scripts for IS4