# Migrate EF Core tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using `dotnetcore 2.0`. I need to know how to programatically `migrate` when a change to the `Model` is made. Change to a Model can be add a new column, edit a column, delete a column or table.

Since EF core does not support automatic migrations like in EF 6, can someone suggest a new way to do this ?

Comment: You need to run migrations from efcore tools,  there are 2 different syntaxes, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42600636/how-can-i-generate-identity-db-scripts-without-migration) same concept applied just with your customContext

Comment: I want to do it via the code, and not by typing commands. @johnny5

Comment: Oops I didn't read that part.  Check out my answer that should put you on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use this for seeding data but migrations run as well.

```
public static void Migrate(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{

    using (var scope = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
         //replace with your dbContext
         var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>();
        context.Database.Migrate();
    }
}
```

Then from your program main you

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var host = BuildWebHost(args);

    Migrate(host.Services);
    host.Run();
}
```

Once it does I believe it uses the EF Models to run migrations on your db

Comment: Could you tell me what happens here

Comment: Bascially when you pass the seed argument it will run migrations first, you can also use that to populate some default values in your db

Comment: Do I need the seed part as well to have Migrations ? I mean the code in the Main function

Comment: No, I just did that to show you how you can do it if you don’t want to run it every time. If you want to run it every time remove the argument and call ensure seed from main or startup

Comment: Ok. I made a change to my Model with the intention of testing the code, and ran the program. In the console it says `No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.` So the change I made in the Model hasn't been picked up.

Comment: I think you still need to update the migrations scripts for each change you want to take affect, not too sure how to do that maybe add prebuilt process

Comment: Not too sure add a prebuilt script to call Dotnet ef migrations update only your context?